# authentication using android + nodejs

Tags: javascript, android, node.js, postgresql

I am trying to build a android app with nodejs on the server using postgresql as database, some days ago I used passport to do a simple authentication in a website.

But with android I want to keep the session alive even if the user doens't have connection with the server. So maybe I need to save the session on device cache.

So I want to register, login, save the session on the device and keep authenticated. How can I do something like that with the mobile device? Is it a good idea to use passport? I searched a lot, but I don't seem to figure out a good solution for this.

Comment: It is not a problem until it is comprehensible. It is enough if you are careful with these [most basic rules](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/291370/1783163).

Comment: well you are right i try to be careful

Answer (score 0):

PassportJS is definitely good for this purpose.
I ended up using [JSON web tokens](https://jwt.io/) for authentication from the Android App.
You won't have to maintain session if you are using JWT.
Here is a simple tutorial to use JWT with passport: [JWT and PassportJS](https://scotch.io/tutorials/authenticate-a-node-js-api-with-json-web-tokens)
All you have to do is obtain the token from the server and cache it on Android.
After you understand the JWT and Passport flow, it will be much easier to think about handling it on Android.

Alternatively, if you want to use sessions, you can take some help from this repo: [Passportjs-Session-Android](https://github.com/dzt/MobilePassport)